# Extract files that start with number to a directory

Tags: bash, syntax

I have many files in a directory that some of them starts with special characters, spaces , number etc.
Now I want to find the files that starts with numbers and put them in a directory.
Then find the files that starts with spaces and put them in a different directory, and then the same procedure for files start with capitals.

```
#!/bin/sh

for nfile in *.png ; do

if [ $nfile=^[0-9]*] ; then
   mkdir NUMBERS
   cp `echo $nfile`  NUMBERS

fi
done
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all recommendations made there.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop. Do simply:

```
mkdir NUMBERS SPACES UPPER
cp [[:digit:]]*.png NUMBERS/
cp [[:space:]]*.png SPACES/
cp [[:upper:]]*.png UPPER/
```

etc.

Comment: Nice answer. Just disturbing that it's a glob with regex class

Comment: @GillesQuenot How is that disturbing?

Comment: Because `[[:class:]]` comes from regex (but works too in `glob`s

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes, and it is also used in pattern matching for filename expansion (inside a bracket expression). So what?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

for space

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name ' *' -exec cp {} space_dir \;
```

for numbers

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[0-9]*' -exec cp {} number_dir \;
```

etc...